# Devising a test strategy

Tags: c++, testing, gwt

As part of a new job, I have to devise and implement a complete test strategy for the company's new product. So far, all I really know about it is that it is written in C++, uses an SQL database and has a web API which is used by a browser client written using GWT.

As far as I know, there isn't much of an existing strategy, except for using Python scripts to test the web API.

I need to develop and implement a suitable strategy for unit, system, regression and release testing, preferably a fully automated one.
I'm looking for good references for:

1. Devising the complete test strategy.
2. Testing the web API.
3. Testing the GWT based application.
4. Unit testing C++ code.

In addition, any suitable tools would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Testing Computer Software](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471358460) is a great soup-to-nuts book on the entire testing process. In addition to the items you mentioned, you'll need to think about other types of testing (performance, security, localization, stress testing, to name a few) and how to manage the test process; test plans, issue tracking, test data, test cases, in addition to the tools.

There's a lot there, and you can't do everything at once. I think a phased approach would be best, where you identify the gaps, weaknesses, and risks in the current process, prioritize them, then set up a high level plan to address them one by one.

[Software QA Testing and Test Tool Resources](http://www.aptest.com/resources.html) is a good starting place for finding some tools to fit your process. [StickyMinds](http://www.stickyminds.com/) is a nice web site dedicated to software testing, and the folks here at StackOverflow certainly know their stuff, so don't be afraid to ask.

Good luck :)

Comment: +1 - Good links. I'm going to forward Testing Computer Software over to a friend in our Q/A area.

Answer (score 3):

You can find a ton of excellent information on testing and developing a test strategy in general over on James Bach's blog. Specifically by searching through it for [tips on testing strategies](http://www.satisfice.com/blog/index.php?s=testing+strategy).

James is an excellent resource for information about how to do **great** software testing.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

There's a good conversation here on [The Purpose of a Test Strategy](http://www.softwaretestingclub.com/forum/topics/751045:Topic:4061).

Answer (score 0):

As testing tools you could use [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) for web testing and [CppUnit](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/cppunit/index.php?title=Main_Page) for c++ unit testing.